# How maven pom.xml file convert configurations into system properties?

Tags: maven, maven-3

As we all know, suppose we define 'transportation' in pom.xml in maven, 
after we run command like 'mvn jetty:run' the property 'db.name' can be discovered by other configuration, like 'hibernate.cfg.xml'.  That's fine.

But now, I configure this project to run on tomcat directly , by 'run on server' from eclipse, instead of by maven command. (I did this by configure a project facets in eclipse, make it can use 'run on server' menu).   You can see now I just run with eclipse, nothing to do with 'maven' or 'pom.xml', but it still use properties like 'db.name'. If I need change to another db, I had to change the 'db.name' property, then run some command in maven to make it take effect.

Can any body give some explanation about how it works? Does maven command generate some file at some place that takes the properties?

Answer (score 0):

Properties are set for virtual machine. Maven run new/existing (dependent on configuration) instance of runtime environment. So you can pass properties as

`-Dkey=value` (or `<key>value</key>` in pom)

Check in eclipse configuration if you can pass arguments when you run tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse maven plugin (from Eclipse foundation) understands the pom.xml and usually syncs with any changes.

But sometimes I observed that it goes out of sync, and to fix that problem I need to delete the temporary folders/files created by Eclipse (.settings, .classpath and .project) and import again.